# delayed_job not using Rails.cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rake, delayed-job

I have a method that accesses a value being stored using Rails.cache. When I execute this method via the console, it uses the cache and everything is fine. However, when the method is executed by a delayed_job worker, it doesn't use the cache.

The worker is being started using the following command:

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work RAILS_ENV=production
```

How do I get delayed_job to use the cache?

EDIT: The application is using dalli_store (a memcached client).

Comment: Have you ever figured out this? I think I'm having exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're might be using in-memory cache, therefore the processes don't share this memory. Check that you don't have a cache_store set to nil.
You can use a file_store or memcache_store (see https://github.com/mperham/dalli)

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that I'm using dalli_store, which is a memcached client.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you checked it, but just to make sure - did you check that in your production environment you're using dalli_store?